# In ElysiaJS, is there a way to print a log to the console after either an error or a successful response, using one single life cycle hook?

Tags: javascript, backend, middleware, bun, elysiajs

I'm learning Elysia by writing a simple log hook (hooks are like middleware in Elysia). I'm looking for a way to print the log by only using one hook.

I've read through the Essential section of the docs [here](https://elysiajs.com/essential/life-cycle.html), and through some other loggers like [elysia-logging](https://github.com/otherguy/elysia-logging/blob/main/src/helpers.ts), and can't find an answer.

Right now, in order to print a log after a successful response or a request error, I need to use both `onResponse` and `onError` life cycle hooks. Something like:

```
import { Elysia } from 'elysia'

new Elysia()
  .onResponse(() => console.log('can this be done with one hook?'))
  .onError(() => console.log('can this be done with one hook?'))
  .get('/', () => 'example with two hooks')
  .listen(3000)
```

And I'm looking for something more like:

```
import { Elysia } from 'elysia'

new Elysia()
  .onAllRepliesAtTheEnd(() => console.log('can this be done with one hook?'))
  .get('/', () => 'example with two hooks')
  .listen(3000)
```

Is there a life cycle hook that works like the above example that uses the non-existent `onAllRepliesAtTheEnd` hook? Or do I need to write a separate `console.log`, one for `onResponse` and one for `onError`?

Is there a life cycle that happens after either a response or an error happens? Or is there no life cycle connection between response and error after they happen?